# Convergence domain of: $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac {(3x-5)^{2n-3}n!}{n^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Find the convergence domain of: $\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac {(3x-5)^{2n-3}n!}{n^n}$

My attempt:

Define $t=3x-5$ so: $\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac {t^{2n-3}n!}{n^n}$.

Finding the convergence disk: I get $R=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {n!}{n^n}\frac{(n+1)^n}{(n+1)!}= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1 {n+1}(\frac {n+1}n)^n  =\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1 {n+1}(1+\frac 1 n)^n=0$ Does that mean that the series diverges or converges only at a single point?

If it converges only at one point, the next step is to check for convergence for $t=0\to x=\frac 5 3$ which makes it the zero series.

Comment: The calculation of $R$ is not right.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I used the ratio test for power series. It's pretty simple, I'll add the steps.

Comment: Yes, the Ratio Test is the natural thing to use. I think that (if we forget about the $x$ stuff in the calculation) the limit should be $1/e$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas ok added, I don't see an error...

Comment: On top you should have $(n+1)^{n+1}$ instead of $(n+1)^n$. That gives limit $e$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas right, damn..

Comment: Ok so that changes the rest but in general if $R=0$ then does that mean the series diverges or might converge only at a single point? @AndréNicolas

Comment: There is automatic convergence at $t=0$. If the radius of convergence is $0$ then we have divergence for all other $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that 
$$\frac{n!}{n^n}\approx \frac{C\sqrt{n}}{e^n}$$
hence the series is divergent for sure if $|3x-5|^2 \geq e$ and convergent for sure if $|3x-5|^2 < e$.

Comment: Why is it to the power of 2?

Comment: Also, how do you know for sure it's divergent at $|e|$?

Comment: @kuhaku: leaving out $\frac{1}{t^3}$, you have to study the convergence of $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{t^{2n}\,n!}{n^n}\approx C\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{t^2}{e}\right)^n \sqrt{n}$$ that obviously depends on $|t^2/e|$ being less than one or not.

Comment: @kuhaku: when $|t^2/e|=1$, the general term of the last series does not converge to zero, hence the series is not convergent.

Comment: But for $t=-e$ we get an alternating decreasing series which converges from the alternating series test.

Comment: Oh never mind it's an even power...